# HTML stored in database showing as text on page

Tags: php, database, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm trying to display this html receipt that's stored in my database as TEXT in a bootstrap modal. The snippet shows the correct way I want it displayed and all the HTML in that snippet is exactly how I store it in my database. Any pointers would be great...not sure where to go from here. I can paste the HTML into a blank document and it will display correctly. It displays as text within my application.

Thanks!

```
<td align="center">
   <table style="table-layout:fixed;width:380px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <pre style="width:380px">
         <div style="text-align:center"><img src="https://hdcontent.homedepot.com/eReceipt/Images/A10F9F74B02AEB4A9FCB403DB87D8B12.jpg"></div>
         <div style="text-align:center">&nbsp;</div>
         <div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">901 CIVIC DRIVE</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">NILES, IL 60714        847-967-3200</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:center">&nbsp;</div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">  1907  00001  51555    09/25/17  12:07 PM</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">  CASHIER DIANE</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:center">&nbsp;</div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">  081099027833 4X8 ULTRALIT &lt;A&gt;          </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">     1/2&quot;X4'X8' USG ULTRALIGHT DRYWALL</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">     6@6.49                         38.94 </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">  751361490046 8FT CRNRBD &lt;A&gt;            </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">     8' GALVANIZED DRYWALL CORNER BEAD</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">     8@1.36                         10.88 </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">  081099000164 EZ SAND 45 &lt;A&gt;        6.98 </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">     18LB-EZ SAND-45MIN COMPOUND</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">  081099000171 EZ SAND90 &lt;A&gt;         6.98 </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">     18LB-EZ SAND-90MIN COMPOUND</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">  038662612088 P-FINISH TPE &lt;A&gt;      8.48 </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">     1-7/8&quot;X300' ULTATHIN MESH JOINT TAPE</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">  081099015861 4.5 CT PLUS3 &lt;A&gt;     10.39 </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">     USG &#43;3 JC PIGMENTED BOX 4.5 GAL</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">  764666103221 15/8CRDWSC5# &lt;A&gt;     13.65 </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">     1-5/8&quot; COARSE DRYWALL SCREW 5 LB</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">  750298153253 2X4-96 STUD &lt;A&gt;           </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">     2X4-96&quot; PRIME KD WHITEWOOD STUD</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">     8@3.06                         24.48 </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">  621241102089 1X2X8 FVRR &lt;A&gt;            </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">     1X2-8FT STRIP</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">     3@0.97                          2.91 </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">  090489089597 LATH &lt;A&gt;             13.97 </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">     48&quot; WOOD LATH - 50 PC BUNDLE</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:center">&nbsp;</div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">                   SUBTOTAL        137.66</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">                   SALES TAX        14.11</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">                   TOTAL          $151.77</span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">  XXXXXXXXXXXX8796 VISA       </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">                              USD$ 151.77 </span></div>
         <div style="text-align:left">
         <span style="font-size:10.0pt;color:black">
```

Comment: HTML works fine in a Bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `{!! $variable !!}` instead of `{{ $variable }}` to display your texts. But consider this from the documentation *Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your application. Always use the escaped, double curly brace syntax to prevent XSS attacks when displaying user supplied data.*

Comment: Please be advised that (how bad of a convention that may be) OP's are often just copy-pasting code from SO answers, when anybody will use your code this might lead to **very severe security risks**, please always inform OP of these risks clearly in your post. (Unescaped HTML is susceptible to store XSS attacks)

Comment: Thanks guys. The receipt data would never be supplied by the user, just displayed to them. Is it ok to store it as i do now? (The above code)?  The above answer fixed my displayed but now the modal-body content shows up on my main page and not the modal.. I have my {!! $expense->receipt_html !!} inside my modal-body div.